# Casting a value to Decimal

Tags: c#, entity-framework, decimal

Here is my code:

```
var finiGames = myRepos.Games
                       .Where(x => x.StatusGameId == (int)StatusGameEnum.Finish 
                              && x.EndDateTime > DateTime.Today)
                       .DefaultIfEmpty();
//error line
decimal? sum = finiGames.Sum(x => x.WinCost);
```

The error I am getting:

> Error converting cast a value type "Decimal", because materializuemoe
>   value is null. The overall result of the type parameter or a request
>   to use a type that allows the value null.

What is the proper way to get a `decimal?`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast the `WinCost` to a `nullable` `decimal` inside the `Sum`

```
decimal? sum = finiGames.Sum(x => (decimal?)x.WinCost);
```

Comment: Could this have been avoided if WinCost was nullable in the first place? Having the Game object in the OP might have helped in this regard.

Comment: @Killnine Yes, if the `WinCost` column was `nullable` the cast would not be needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
decimal sum = ((decimal?)finiGames.Sum(x => x.WinCost)) ?? 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `ToList()` to `finiGames`. It might kill your performance, but EF probably can't handle the conversion in the data (SQL) layer.